# Realizar un gráfico combinado

Tags: r

Necesito realizar un gráfico combinado con lineas y barras con los siguientes datos:

```
NU <- c(0,180,90,0,0,0,90,180,0,0,180,90,0,0,0)
NCP <- c (180,0,0,0,360,360,0,0,180,0,0,0,180,0,360)
Rend<- c(14083,20856,19273,9655,15171,14021,14794,17578,11196,7201,13869,14114,8281,6041,12251)
S <- data.frame(NU=NU,NCP=NCP,Rend=Rend)
S
```

Separo el dataframe con los datos de NU (donde NCP=0) y realizo un regresión lineal y obtengo su gráfico de esta manera:

```
dataNU <- subset(S, NCP == "0")
LmNU<-lm(Rend ~ (NU+ I(NU^2)), data = dataNU)
summary(LmNU)

dataNU%>%   
  ggplot(aes(x=NU, y=Rend)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x + I(x^2), 
              method = "lm",
              se=FALSE) +
  labs(x="NU",  
       y="Kg") + 
  theme_minimal()
```

Me faltaría ahora agregar barras con las medias de los datos de NCP=180 y NCP=360, para que quede mas o menos de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el caso de que se pudiera colocar las lineas punteadas que trasladan el valor de las barras a la curva y de ahí a la ordenadas de las x, fantástico, si no, no pasa nada.

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Que medirían estas barras? El valor máximo de cada NCP? La media?

Comment: Si, perdón, las barras deberían representar la media. Edito la pregunta para que quede más claro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combinar los dos gráficos es relativamente sencillo en este caso ya que estamos trabajando básicamente con los mismos datos y los mismos ejes. Podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
S %>%   
ggplot() +
geom_point(data=dataNU, aes(x=NU, y=Rend)) +
geom_smooth(data=dataNU,
            formula = y ~ x + I(x^2), 
            method = "lm",
            se=FALSE,
            aes(colour="", x=NU, y=Rend) ) +
scale_colour_manual(name="NU", values=c("blue")) +
labs(x="NU",  
     y="Kg") + 
geom_bar(data=S,
         aes(x=NCP, y=Rend), 
         stat = "summary", 
         width=30, 
         alpha = c(0,0.3,0.3), 
         fill = "red", 
         fun.y = "mean") +
theme_minimal()
```

#### Resutado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Detalle:

- Como habrás visto, tenemos que usar el `dataframe` completo ya que queremos graficar una barra para `NP==360` y usando el conjunto `subset(S, NCP == "0")` excluimos estos valores. Pero en el resto de los componentes usamos el `subset` que ya armaste `dataNU`
- Agregamos un [`geom_bar()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/1.0.1/topics/geom_bar) a la gráfica, la misma va a ser del tipo `summary` y la función sumaria va a ser la media (`fun.y = "mean"`)
- En tu ejemplo pareciera que no quieres una barra para `NP == 0`, si usamos el `dataframe` completo, nos generará una barra para este grupo, pero hay un truco que es configurar la transparencia para que no se vea: `alpha = c(0,0.3,0.3)`

Lo siguiente es ver como dibujamos las rectas horizontales y verticales. Esto no es del todo trivial, al menos para mí, ya que en primer lugar tenemos que encontrar un punto dónde la recta horizontal cuyo `y` (que se corresponde a la media de  cada `NU`) intersecciona con la curva de regresión, el tema es que justamente la regresión nos sirve para determinar un punto `y` dado cualquier `x` pero no a la inversa.

Seguramente hay formas más directas, pero me falta teoría, así que como no has mencionado que necesites precisión en este punto, vamos a usar una forma aproximativa para llegar a estos puntos. La idea es usar `predict()` obtener todos los `y` (`Rend`) de cada punto del eje `x` (`NU`) de 0 a 360 en pasos de 0.1 (se pude ajustar este número para lograr mayor precisión), con estos números simplemente buscaremos aquel que más se aproxime a la media de cada barra:

```
# Calculamos la media de los valores de NCP 180 y 360
bar_means <- c(mean(S[S$NCP==180,3]), mean(S[S$NCP==360,3]))

# A lo cavernicola, generamos los y de la curva, luego
# buscamos el x mas cercano a la media de cada barra
model<-lm(Rend ~ (NU+ I(NU^2)), data = dataNU)
newx <-data.frame(NU=seq(0,360,0.1))
fitline = predict(model, newdata=newx)

xnew <- c(min(newx[fitline>bar_means[1],]),
          min(newx[fitline>bar_means[2],])
)
```

Con esto puntos ya podemos definir los segmentos desde cada barra a la curva y de esta al eje `x`.

```
# Generamos los datos para dibujar los segmentos verticales y horizontales
lineas_h <- data.frame(
    pos = bar_means,
    start = c(180, 360),
    end = xnew
)

lineas_v <- data.frame(
    pos = xnew,
    start = bar_means,
    end = c(0, 0)
)
```

Con estos datos, podemos usar [`geom_segment()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/2.2.1/topics/geom_segment) para dibujar estas líneas. Además podremos agregar las leyendas, pero tendremos una para cada barra (incluida la del 0) con colores distintos, por que efectivamente son grupos distintos, el código completo sería:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
NU <- c(0,180,90,0,0,0,90,180,0,0,180,90,0,0,0)
NCP <- c (180,0,0,0,360,360,0,0,180,0,0,0,180,0,360)
Rend<- c(14083,20856,19273,9655,15171,14021,14794,17578,11196,7201,13869,14114,8281,6041,12251)
S <- data.frame(NU=NU,NCP=NCP,Rend=Rend)
S

dataNU <- subset(S, NCP == "0")

# Calculamos la media de los valores de NCP 180 y 360
bar_means <- c(mean(S[S$NCP==180,3]), mean(S[S$NCP==360,3]))

# A lo cavernicola, generamos los y de la curva y 
# buscamos el x mas cercano a la media de cada barra
model<-lm(Rend ~ (NU+ I(NU^2)), data = dataNU)
newx <-data.frame(NU=seq(0,360,0.1))
fitline = predict(model, newdata=newx)

xnew <- c(min(newx[fitline>bar_means[1],]),
          min(newx[fitline>bar_means[2],])
)

# Generamos los datos para dibujar los segmentos verticales y horizontales
lineas_h <- data.frame(
    pos = bar_means,
    start = c(180, 360),
    end = xnew
)

lineas_v <- data.frame(
    pos = xnew,
    start = bar_means,
    end = c(0, 0)
)

# Plot sobre el data.frame completo
S %>%   
    ggplot() +
    geom_point(data=dataNU, aes(x=NU, y=Rend)) +
    geom_smooth(data=dataNU,
                formula = y ~ x + I(x^2), 
                method = "lm",
                se=FALSE, 
                aes(colour="", x=NU, y=Rend) 
                ) + 
    scale_colour_manual(name="NU", values=c("blue")) +
    labs(x="NU",  
         y="Kg") + 
    geom_bar(data=S,
             aes(x=NCP, y=Rend, fill = factor(NCP)), 
             stat = "summary", 
             width=30, 
             alpha = c(0,0.3,0.3), 
             fun.y = "mean") +
    geom_segment(data=lineas_h,aes(x=start, y=pos, xend=end, yend=pos), linetype=2) +
    geom_segment(data=lineas_v,aes(y=start, x=pos, yend=end, xend=pos), linetype=2) +
    labs(fill="NCP") +
    theme_minimal()
```

## Y el resultado final

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado:

Comment: Patricio, muchísimas gracias, la gráfica quedo genial!!
Si tuve un porblema cuando calculola media de los valores de NCP, dandome el siguiente error:

Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(graphdata[graphdata$NCP == 180, 3]) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(graphdata[graphdata$NCP == 360, 3]) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Por lo que no pude agregar las lineas. Igualmente eso es secundario, pero se pueden estar mejor.
Además ¿se podría agregar una leyenda?
Gracias!

Comment: Revisa si `graphdata$NCP` no es un factor, en cuyo caso lo más fácil es convertir previamente la columna en numérica con `as.numeric` y ahí el calculo de la media debería funcionar bien.

Comment: Lo hice pero no resulto. Lo que termine haciendo fue crear el dataframe de la consola y no importándolo desde el excel y ahí si funciono.
Gracias!

Comment: Como podría agregar la leyenda al gráfico?

Comment: @germanfernandez, a que te refieres con leyenda? te refieres a las etiquetas NCP y NU con los colores?

Comment: Si, a un cuadro que indique que la linea azul es NU y las barras rojas son NCP.

Comment: @germanfernandez, algo se puede hacer pero no exactamente igual a tu ejemplo, revisa mi última edición.

Comment: Bien, no importa que las barras tengan colores distintos. Lo que si recién me di cuenta es que la curva que describe el NU no es la correcta, ya que como valor 0 está tomando además de sus valores los valores de NCP, haciendo que en el valor 0 este más arriba de lo que debería estar. Yo trate de arreglarlo con el comando subset  antes de ingersar tu codigo pero así no puedo colocar las barras, ¿cómo se podría arreglar?

Comment: @germanfernandez Si es cierto, lo que se puede hacer es que la regresión, `geom_point` y `geom_smooth`  se calculen sobre `dataNU` y el resto de los componentes sobre el `data.frame` completo. Revisa mi última edición.

Comment: Lujo @pmoracho, funciono perfecto. Muchisimas gracias!!